# internal ssd won't open and home folder icon doesn't work

Tags: ssd

I am a 69 year old newcomer to Linux and ubuntu I am running ubuntu 22.04.2 I downloaded Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2 and now my internal SSD drive won't open and the home folder icon doesn't work, what have I done wrong.

What happened was I bought a new computer with Ubuntu 22.04.2LTS installed, I want to use the computer for my photography and some video editing and also recording some music.

There are so many programs out there I got lost trying to find which I should use for each purpose, then I came across Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2 LTS. I thought this is what I have been looking for everything in one package so I followed the instructions on downloading, so I went to the web site the choice it gives you are direct download with Plasma desktop or if you didn't want plasma then go to terminal and type `sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer` so I looked to see what people were saying about Plasma, people said it was cool so I downloaded Ubuntu studio, it said to be able to install it you needed to have Ubuntu already installed I thought that's me and clicked download, it took about 16 minutes I went to downloads and there are two files there

One file with a lock on it that says ubuntustud io-22.04.2 dvd-amd64 ,the other is a box with a disk inside with iso writen on it, that says ubuntustud io -22.04.2 dvd-amd so I tried to open the files that's when my problems began I think

If I clicked on them I was taken to more files that I had no idea what to do with, so then I thought maybe  I need to get the installer so I typed in terminal `sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer` a window came up asking which packages I wanted to install I selected all of them except for enable backports PPA my computer started downloading lots of things for photography music vedieo etc I thought great I have all the things I need,I have a one Tb boot drive and I have a 1 Tb ssd hard drive in the computer for storage and I have downloaded some files on to it with some photos

But when I clicked on the ssd icon in my favourites bar it wont open, the name of the drive comes up with a turning circle but I can't access my files, also when I click on my home folder it doesn't work, if I open gimp and try to open a photo the ssd drive dosen't show up in gimp,

I'm lost, Is there anyway I can uninstall what I have done ?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me sorry (*it maybe unclear to others too*). You mention both Ubuntu 22.04 & Ubuntu Studio 22.04, so is this a dual install? or are you just referring to Ubuntu Studio as Ubuntu? What do you mean by SSD won't open, is that in an app? if so which app (`dolphin`? (file-manager used by Ubuntu Studio) `nautilus`? (file-manager used by Ubuntu Desktop) or something else?  If you're not familiar with the app names, that's fine, just describe the best you can, or take a picture & add a URL/link to where we can view it to your question maybe.

Comment: Hi guiverc ,thank you for responding I have now edited my post

Comment: It reads like you download (one or two) ISO files. Those are used to install the Ubuntu Studio OS, either *alongside* or *replacing* your existing Ubuntu system. I'm not sure that's what you want. Ubuntu Desktop uses the GNOME desktop, Ubuntu Studio just uses KDE Plasma instead of GNOME, so the GUI (graphical user interface) looks & operates different, but achieves the ~same thing. Ubuntu Studio is geared for *content creators*, ie. creating video/audio etc creations; is this what you're trying to do?  You do mention creating new music & editing videos so yes.

Comment: My understanding of what you did was download & then open the Ubuntu Studio ISO. What you're intended to do is write the ISO to installation media; then boot that media so as to install it. I'd forget the ISO you downloaded for now (*use it only if you decide to install using it*).  Using the `ubuntustudio-installer` to me was your best approach; ie. adding packages to your existing system. Those packages should appear in your normal menus as options.

Comment: Don't try and explore the ISO (DVD) files & look for anything you can directly run; the ISO is compressed files that get installed before they're used (ie. written to thumb-drive, booted, installed first, then on booting into the newly installed system they'll appear in menus).  This is what I suspect you were doing; and getting confused (*easily done*)

Comment: Hi, guiverc thank you for your explanation, so when I downloaded ubuntu studio the first time I should have made a bootable USB stick then installed it from there.

Comment: No, the ISO is an alternative to the `ubuntustudio-installer` you ran. The [Ubuntu-Studio-installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) you ran added all the unique bits of Ubuntu Studio to your existing system, but left your existing desktop (*at least that's what I believe you did; you can check the link I provided for more clues; the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntustudio-installer) is largely a [script](https://launchpad.net/ubuntustudio-installer) that you can run to grab what you want from Ubuntu Studio; it's what I'd try first in your case*)

Comment: Hi guiverc,again thank you for your help, I downloaded ubuntu desktop on to a flash drive and reinstalled it, everything now works again and I can access my photos and files on my internal ssd drive, I will now look for suitable packages for my needs.